# replacing columns names in a data frame based on an other table

Tags: r

I have a data frame :

```
v1 <- c(100, 20, 5, 30)
v2 <- c(10, 13, 2, 30)
v3 <- c(10, 200, 5, 300)
df <- data.frame(v1, v2, v3)
```

The output :

```
   v1 v2  v3
 1 100 10  10
 2  20 13 200
 3   5  2   5
 4  30 30 300
```

I have an index table :

```
id <- c("v1", "v2", "v3")
label <- c("number of people", "number of schools", "number of females")
index <- data.frame(id, label)**
```

The output :

```
  id       label
1 v1       number of people
2 v2       number of schools
3 v3       number of females
```

I have an index table that matches variables identifiers and labels. How to replace column names in my dataset based on the index table ?

Expected output :

```
  "number of people" "number of schools" "number of females"
 1 100               10                 10
 2  20               13                 200
 3   5               2                  5
 4  30               30                 300
```

Comment: Did you test the accepted answer? Try with `df <- data.frame(v3, v2, v1)`

Comment: @Ronak Shah Yes. I tested it with success. Alls answers are greats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dplyr::rename:

```
df %>% rename_all(function(x) index$label[index$id == x])

  number of people number of schools number of females
1              100                10                10
2               20                13               200
3                5                 2                 5
4               30                30               300
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `match` :

```
names(df) <- index$label[match(names(df), index$id)]
df
#  number of people number of schools number of females
#1              100                10                10
#2               20                13               200
#3                5                 2                 5
#4               30                30               300
```